# Controlling blocks displayed in domain access for each sub-domain

Tags: domain-access, blocks

I'm a noob in Drupal and have been exploring the Domain Access module ( http://drupal.org/project/domain ) in my local environment and till now has been doing pretty well. But when it comes to configuring block content i'm a bit baffled. 
Problem goes like this:
domain is localhost.com
Sub domains are:

- one.localhost.com
- two.localhost.com
- three.localhost.com

When i enable a block in one of the sub-domains two.localhost, say enabling Search in Right Sidebar and saving the changes they are applied not only to two.localhost but to all the others too.

Note that I'm working in drupal 6.22 with Garland theme in all the sub domains. 
Is there anything I'm missing from the functionalities provided by the module like Domain Theme? or does it have to be coded by me to make blocks also in domain specific manner...any suggestions/helps would be much appreciated.

Thanks and cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've a module that gonna help you. [Domain Blocks](http://drupal.org/project/domain_blocks). And [here](http://drupal.org/node/1068570) you've many other that add some features to Domain Access module.

Comment: just to proceed on this does using domain prefix module with blocks related table serve as an alternative to this?

Comment: Yes, but the created blocks will not shared between all domains. And you've to prefix `blocks` and `boxes` and all related block tables (for example, cache and etc..)